# How do you fix Bluetooth connect issues with a logitech M650 mouse on the macOS Monterey?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, bluetooth, mouse

I have a Logitech M650. I recently hit "forget this device" and I now want to un-forget it. I have tried manually re-pairing it through Bluetooth and it automatically pairs up, in that scenario.

The problem comes when I try using the USB to connect to my laptop, then try using the Bluetooth again, my laptop forgets its Bluetooth connection and I have to manually reconnect the Bluetooth every time, after using the USB.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Pairing means the Bluetooth device exists in your preferences when it’s powered off. Can you confirm if you have sporadic auto reconnect issues or if you really have it automatically re-pairing. The second situation isn’t possible AFAIK.